# How to update a document which contains array of another Schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have Task Schema and User Schema in one file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "must provide name"],
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [20, "name can not be more than 20 characters"],
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date,
    completedAt: Date,
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Must provide name"],
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [20, "Name cannot be more than 20 characters"],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, "Must provide email"],
        validator: {
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: "Please provide valid email",
        },
    },
    pass: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Must provide password"],
    },
    verificationToken: String,
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    verifiedAt: Date,
    tasks: {
        type: [TaskSchema],
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Now I want to update/insert task in `tasks` array inside UserSchema. So how do I update a document with a document of different Schema. I'm only storing Users in database, not Tasks. Also is this the correct way of defining array of TaskSchema in UserSchema?

I searched a lot but couldn't get an proper answer.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

## You can change the schema like this.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");

const Task = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "must provide name"],
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [20, "name can not be more than 20 characters"],
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date,
    completedAt: Date,
});

const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Must provide name"],
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [20, "Name cannot be more than 20 characters"],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, "Must provide email"],
        validator: {
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: "Please provide valid email",
        },
    },
    pass: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Must provide password"],
    },
    verificationToken: String,
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    verifiedAt: Date,
    tasks: {
        type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Task' }],
    },
});

const taskSchema = mongoose.model('Task', Task),
const userSchema = mongoose.model('organizations', User)

module.exports = { User: taskSchema, Organization: userSchema }
```